# Toggle only works the first time

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use the Toggle Button to play a sound when the button is "on" and stop the sound when the button is "off".

This seems to only work when I first toggle between the on/off button.

```
ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);

toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
 public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
  if (isChecked) {
   // The toggle is enabled
   sound1.start();
  } else {
   // The toggle is disabled
   sound1.stop();
  }
 }
});
```

Comment: Did you check if the `isChecked` works and changes on each click event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you called method stop().
There is the description of the method:

*Calling stop() stops playback and causes a MediaPlayer in the Started, Paused, Prepared or PlaybackCompleted state to enter the Stopped state.
    Once in the Stopped state, playback cannot be started until prepare() or prepareAsync() are called to set the MediaPlayer object to the Prepared state again.
    Calling stop() has no effect on a MediaPlayer object that is already in the Stopped state.*

How to play exactly right,you just need to visit this website of google. [click me.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)

Comment: Thank you , it was because I used the method stop(), i have opted to use pause() and then seekTo(0) to reset my sound back to the start.

Answer (score 0):

So the best thing that you can is to use a class constant to check if the flag is already set. You will need to save this to the savedCacheInstance when onPause/onStop/OnDestroy and then reload it. Something like:

```
boolean isMusicPlaying = false;
```

If you save this using savedInstanceCache in both onCreate & onStop/onDestroy, you can control the playback between rotations and start ups/exits. The class property is also inside the class scope of the listener so that any action you take, should update the class property. The best way to identify any issue is to of course, use the debugger. That way you can control the play functions and see which is breaking.